# Type casting needed with byte datatype when doing addition?

Tags: java

I have the problem with following code:

```
     byte b=34;  //successfully compiled
     b=b+10;     //compile time error
     int x=34;   //success
     b=x;        //compile time error
```

Why is `b=34` compiled successfully, while integer literal is by default int
but `b=x` gives compile time error while x is int ?

Comment: Read -  Assignment Conversion- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html

Comment: byte b=128 also gives compile time error as we try to assign a value greater than 127.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `byte b` is a byte of 8 bits and `int x` is a 32 bits integer value.

Therefore, your code `b=b+10` can be translated as

```
b = 00100011b + 00000000000000000000000000001010b;
```

As you can see, the JVM will cannot force `byte b` to an int (by shoving 32 bits value into an 8 bit registry), so there's type incompatibility, if typecasting is not done (the same applies for `b=x`).

Answer (score 2):

With out casting it's not possible, see `The Elite Gentleman` answer.

do casting this way

```
byte b=34;
b=(byte)(b+10);
int x=34;
b=(byte)x;
```

Answer (score 1):

due to possibly loss of precision 
 you should code as follows

```
 byte b=34;
b=(byte)(b+10);
int x=34;
b=(byte)x;
```

Comment: Line 2 will not compile. Try `b += 10;` instead.

Comment: Or put brackets around (b+10)

Answer (score 1):

In your code-snippet the `b=x;` is not *assignable*.

From the [JLS 5.2 Assignment Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html).

> If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the
>   variable by a conversion permitted in an assignment context, then a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Narrowing primitive conversion may be used if all of the following conditions are satisfied:

> 1. The expression is a constant expression of type byte, short, char or int.
> 2. The type of the variable is byte, short, or char.
> 3. The value of the expression (which is known at compile time, because it is a constant expression) is representable in the type of
>      the variable.

Comment: `b=b+10` also has an issue... why doesn't `b+=10`? (Since you already have the specification open...)

Answer (score 1):

When you add `int` to `byte`, the `byte` will be `implicitly` converted into `int` but the conversion `int` to `byte` will not be done implicitly, it should be done explicitly.

```
byte b=34;
b=(byte)(b+10);
int x=34;
b=(byte)x;
```

Comment: So why is `b += 10;` perfectly legal? :)

Comment: b += 10 is perfectly legal, because when we use +=, implicitly type cast is done. first right hand operation is performed and the result is typecasted to the variable type of left hand side. @pst

Comment: thats the operator += functionality. all operators of the form 'op=' cast their result to the type of the left-operand . http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/assignment.html

Answer (score 0):

Because integer datatype can hold much bigger values than byte and there is no trivial rule to  convert int yo byte.

In your case:

```
b = (byte)x;
```

will help,

Answer (score 0):

well byte range is -128 to 12y so you are able to set the value in the while the arithemetic operation you need to convert that byte to integer bcoz it will consider as integer value not as byte value.

you can't directly type cast from integer to byte bcoz integer size is larger than the byte that's why you getting compile time error

check this link for result how the effect on conversion from integer to byte [How does Java convert int into byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842817/760489)