# ORA-01002 Fetch out of sequence oracle when fetching 30 Million records

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to fetch 30 million records through Inputstream.read() suggested in [Java SQL Result to InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209818/java-sql-result-to-inputstream). I'll be processing those records and transfering with GFT. when trying this process, I am getting **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence** error on my resultset. but, it's not happening everytime. I see few success with 30,20 million records. sometimes, i get this error for 15 million records too. Out of sequence thrown after reading some records(not at beginning)

Following is how i am creating my connection & resultset

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
sql = "select query" // I am selecting 30 columns from table
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql); //using PreparedStatement
stmt.fetchSize() // It was set to 300.
rs = stmt.executeQuery(); //resultset
//Not overriding anymore default properties
```

Following are the properties in my config

```
spring.datasource.type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

My oracle version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release

Is there anything i need to override the default connection/stmt/resultset properties? I am not sure, if it's related to connection. I am not able simulate/find out pattern when this was happening.

Query used was
`SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3....COLUMN_30 FROM TABLE_NAME where TIMESTAMP < ? and TIMESTAMP >= ?`
provided timestamps after creating preparedStatement
`stmt.setTimestamp(1, timestamp); stmt.setTimestamp(2, timestamp);`

I was able to debug this once. onething i observed is resultset.next() is throwing this fetch out of sequence error. when i expand delegate object inside the resultset, observed fields are

```
isAllFetched = false
isDoneFetchingRows = false
currentRow = 7035999
fetchedrowCount = 7036000
```

This is the point where resultset.next() throwing Fetch out of sequence

Comment: Please show your exact query. Does it use PL/SQL functions in it?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov updated the post. Not using PL/SQL functions.

Comment: Are you doing any update for the rows and how frequently are you committing the rows , if yes you can remove the Commit and commit only once for all the rows. Can the update  that you are doing in the for loop can it be done by a single SQL statement .

Comment: are you sure that `table_name` is a table, not view?

Comment: I am not doing update on any of the rows and just reading all the columns for each row. I think auto-commit is set to true by default, does that effect me when not doing any update? @hkandpal

Comment: just enable SQL_TRACE (`alter session set sql_trace=TRUE`), repeat the error and provide your raw trace file here.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I am sure it's a table name.

Comment: Are you sure you're detecting the end of fetch properly, and not trying to fetch rows after the last one been fetched? This sometimes happens when you have an issue while looping on the result set and it is not correctly handled.

Comment: @gsalem yes, i think so. and it's not happening every time we read the db records(30 million). only sometime it throws the error. I never seen this error when fetching less records(like 1-5 million).

Comment: Try to disable autocommit

Comment: I am using only select in my sql query, does auto-commit effect that?