# How can i convert an integer to byte?

Tags: java, integer, byte, theory

I want to know how can i convert an integer to byte theoretically.
I mean i don't want to use a predefined program but i want just to know how can i implement it.
What i know that from -128 to 127 an integer is the same as byte but the problemes is from 128 to 128 to +infinite and from -129 to -infinite.
For example given the following code:

```
    Integer a = 140;//10001100 this is his binary conversion
    Byte zz = (byte) a.byteValue();
    System.out.println(zz);// result is -116
```

How that conversion works in java?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte

Comment: Bytes are from `-128` to `127`, the `140` overflows to `-116`.

Comment: you'll notice that 140+116 = 256

Answer (score 3):

That value is out of range of the `Byte` and hence [overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Refer [JLS 4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> 1. **For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive**

A byte is `8` bits , the most significant bit specifies the sign of the number and are are encoded in two's complement.

Read this wonderful [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842900/1163607) for more.

Comment: I know so how can i convert it to byte?

Comment: @BenMansourNizar What result do you want ? It can't store 140 !

Comment: @BenMansourNizar, In theory you can create a list when you will put the parts of Byte. But in reality this is integer or long.

Answer (score 1):

Byte value binary representation will not change, it will still be `10001100` but it will be interpreted differently, since `byte` is a signed type in  two's complement representation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement and since bit 7 is set it means that now it's a negative number -116

Answer (score 1):

when you are *narrowing* a primitive, you must explicitly make a cast - so you acknowledge a possible loss of data.

There is no loss if value is within the -128...127 byte value range

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert value grate than 127 into byte as it do not have place to store it. As 140 in binary is `10001100` it mean that you need a type that store at lest 8 bits. A byte store 8 bits but one of then is reserved for sign. So you can not fit it into it. You can use short witch store 16 bits (15 and 1 for sign).

The zero in different types expressed in binary;

```
byte  b = 0b000_0000;
short s = 0b000_0000_0000_0000;
int   i = 0b000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
```

If you try to declare something like:

```
byte  b = 0b1000_1100;
```

The compiler will tall you `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte`.