# convert integer to byte if the integer is less than 16

Tags: java, android

If I have an integer that will have always a positive number less than 16 , can  I just cast it to byte

```
int i = 5;
byte b = (byte) i;
```

or should I have unexpected behaviour when converting it back to integer on different devices?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "converting it back to integer?" And what about negative values? `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is less than 16, but cannot "fit" in a `byte`.

Comment: This link will probbaly help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte

Comment: Good point. I meant to say the number is always positive and less than 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't get unexpected behaviour converting a `byte` between 0 and 15 into an `int` on different platforms.  One of the strengths of Java is that it precisely defines what happens with such conversions, so that they are always platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the Integer class and use byteValue.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#byteValue()

which simply does

```
return (byte)value;
```