# Why Byte can't hold a value that is within its range?

Tags: java, int, byte, primitive-types

You can't put a large value in small cup. Well, OK, you can, but you'll lose some. You'll get, as we say, spillage. the compiler tries to help prevent this if it can tell from your code that something's not going to fit in container(variable) you are using.

For Example,

```
int x= 24;

byte b= x;

// Won't work!!
```

now range of byte is `-128` to `127`. Now, my question is why doesn't this work? After all, the value of `x` is `24`, and `24` is definitely small enough to fit into byte (may be a very novice level question, but i am really confused about this concept).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte could be useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You* know that `byte b= x;` is equivalent to `byte b= 24;`, and an intelligent compiler can also tell that, but Java is specified in a very precise way to ensure that all compilers do the same thing, and it does not allow compilers to notice this equivalence for purposes of accepting or rejecting the program. (They can use it for performing optimization afterward, though.) All the compiler is supposed to know is that the expression `x` has the static type `int`, so it can't guarantee that `byte b= x` is assigning a value in the range of `byte`.

Instead, you have to write `byte b = (byte) x`, explicitly converting ("casting") the expression `x` to type `byte`.

(This is a general principle with static typing — with any type system, there will always be some otherwise-correct programs that the type system rejects. In this case, the type system doesn't let you assign from `int` to `byte` without a cast.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to typecase your int into a byte this way:

```
byte b = (byte) x;
```

Else the compiler will give you an error at compilation
Keep in mind typecasting comes with loss of data if the value is outside the boundaries for the primitive datatype you are storing in.