# Encoding Uint32 ints into Java byte array

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

I'm using a third party ssh library and I need to specify some options as a byte array. Namely the terminal modes (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4254.txt).

My problem is that I need to create a `byte` array that is the 'equivalent' of a `uint` array `{128, 36000, 129, 36000}` and I am not quite sure on how to achieve that. By equivalent I mean - I don't care what number it represents in java, I do care that the correct bytes are sent down the socket.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In java, an int is 32 bits, so just write ints

Comment: Do you need to send unsigned 32 bits?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte

Comment: No unfortunately I am using a 3rd party library so I *have* to pass in a byte[]. Otherwise I'd simply use an int[]. And yes, I'm aware that bytes in java are signed and thus 128 would overflow, but that is the crux of my question.

Comment: Oh I see, you are not doing the writing to the socket yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, then I believe you can do it with a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) wrapped by a [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and something like this,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
int[] ints = new int[] { 128, 36000, 129, 36000 };
try {
  for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i += 2) {
    dos.writeByte(ints[i]);
    dos.writeInt(ints[1 + i]);
  }
  dos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Or, use the client's [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) directly.

Comment: or simply an OutputStream

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach! I'll give it a go and accept answer if it works :)

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The [write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#write-int-) method of ByteArray *does not* write an int as four bytes;  it writes only the lowest 8 bits of the int.  The above code will create a byte array containing only 4 bytes total!

Comment: @VGR Edited to use a DataOutputStream and writeInt. Which do write four bytes.

Comment: Looking at the RFC linked in the question, I see that the terminal mode opcodes are not actually uint32s, but single bytes;  it is their arguments which are uint32s.  So I'm pretty sure the loop should contain a `writeByte` call followed by a `writeInt` call.  From the RFC: "The stream consists of opcode-argument pairs wherein the opcode is a byte value.  Opcodes 1 to 159 have a single uint32 argument."

Comment: @VGR It does say *The stream consists of opcode-
   argument pairs wherein the opcode is a byte value.  Opcodes 1 to 159
   have a single uint32 argument.* So I edited it to do that.