# Convert int to bytes

Tags: android, int, byte

I had a calendar widget and passed the values to another activity through bundle. How can I, after getting values from bundle, convert "year","month","day" into bytes?

```
    int year = extras.getInt("year");
    int day = extras.getInt("day");
    int month = extras.getInt("month");
```

Comment: You mean byte array? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array

Comment: Can you clarify (by expected outcome) what you mean by "into bytes"?

Comment: Yes , can you tell me the difference between the two also? @ShobhitPuri

Comment: into byte array @leesei .. I want to eventually send them to another device (bluetoothsocket) and i must use byte array.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte

Comment: @user3965683 than converting them to byte array as `shobhit-puri` mentioned is the way to go, you can then be explicit as to how many bytes each `int` consumes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your int to bytes by using a ByteBuffer.

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(year).array();
```