# How casting works in java using modulo

Tags: java, casting, byte

the below code result "39 44" as output. I read somewhere that casting used modulo here. I know basic how to calculate modulo like 10%3 = 1 but I still didn't get how it calculated here.

```
class conversion {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {    
         double a = 295.04;
         int  b = 300;
         byte c = (byte) a;
         byte d = (byte) b;
         System.out.println(c + " "  + d);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465633/type-casting-into-byte-in-java

Comment: You haven't asked for anything using the remainder operator. Rather than relying on something you "read somewhere" but presumably can't provide the details of, I suggest you use the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) to explain the behaviour.

Comment: How that works is precisely defined in the Java Language Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3. And there is no modulo involved.

Comment: @JBNizet there isn't a modulus? This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465633/type-casting-into-byte-in-java) says there is.

Comment: Well, it's wrong.

Comment: @Shashwat: The answers says the result is the same *as if* `%` were used. That's not the same thing. "How does multiplication work" could say that the result of multiplying `x * y` is the same as starting a sum of 0 and adding `x` to it `y` times... but that's not how multiplication happens in the CPU.

Comment: Also, try it with 500, for example, and you'll see that the result of a modulo 128 and the result of the cast are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range of byte is -128 to 127.
    so byte(128) will be -128.
    byte(129) will be -127.
    byte(256) will be 0.
    byte(257)=1
    byte(295)=39.
    byte(295.04)=byte(295)=39.