# Why both (byte) 400000 and (byte) -400000 result -128

Tags: java, casting, byte, twos-complement

In Java, why both (byte) 400000 and (byte) -400000 have result -128?

Actually, I followed the calculation method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085666/1037217

For case: 400000
Binary: 1100001101010000000
Trim to 8 digits: 10000000
Since the left most digit is 1, so -1 from it: 01111111
Then invert it: 10000000
Result: -128

For case: -400000
Binary: -1100001101010000000
Trim to 8 digits: 10000000
Since the left most digit is 1, so -1 from it: 01111111
Then invert it: 10000000
Result: 128

The same method works on 
(short) 40000 = -25536
(short) -40000 = 25536

Comment: it's overflow. you can't store any of these number in byte variable.

Comment: Suppose you gave them a different value. Now take some other pair of numbers, and do the same, and so on. Clearly you'd end up needing more than 256 different bytes, which is by definition impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting an `int` to `byte` will preserve the int number's last 8 bits (the last byte).

```
 400000 = 0x61a80
-400000 = 0xfff9e580
```

Both of your numbers have the same last 8 bits: `0x80` which is `-1` in 2's complement.

For example:

```
System.out.println((byte)0x23403); // Prints 3 (the last 8 bits: 0x03 = 3)
System.out.println((byte)0x23483); // Prints -125 (last 8 bits: 0x83 = -125)
// (in 2's complement: 0x83 = -(128-3) = -125)
```

Comment: Sorry, I added some examples, can you explain them?

Comment: @Felix Just take the last 8 bits. Simple. If you want to understand what number the bits will give you, you need to read about and understand [2's complement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement).

Answer (score 2):

Because `byte` has the range -128 to 127. Both of your values overflow and are then subject to a narrowing conversion. To quote JLS [Example 5.1.3-2. Narrowing Primitive Conversions that lose information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#d5e4314),

> ```
> // An int value too big for byte changes sign and magnitude:
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As you say:

> For case: 400000 Binary: 1100001101010000000 Trim to 8 digits: 10000000 Since the left most digit is 1, so -1 from it: 01111111 Then invert it: 10000000 Result: -128
>
> For case: -400000 Binary: -1100001101010000000 Trim to 8 digits: 10000000 Since the left most digit is 1, so -1 from it: 01111111 Then invert it: 10000000 Result: 128

In both cases, the bit pattern you get is `10000000`. That equates to `-128` both times. A `byte` cannot represent the value `128`; it is out of range.

However, your procedure is not quite right. You can't just put a negative sign there and then "trim to 8 digits". A negative sign is not a valid state for a bit. You should probably study the [2s complement representation of integers](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Etomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).

Comment: Yes, I followed the wrong procedure at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9085666/1037217