# Create an array of byte[] from a int value in Java

Tags: android, foreach, arrays

Considering the following for-each loop

```
        String S = "";
        byte[] sendingByte;
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        try {

            ReadHoldRegisters(lst, 1, 1, 10);
            for (int value : lst) {
                S = S + String.format("%02x ", value);
            }

            etWrite.setText(S);

        } finally {
            // send modbus rtu byte[] array to USB serial port
            }
```

Where `ReadHoldRegisters` generates a `CRC16 ArrayList of Integer` and that `int` in Java is a **signed** value

How can I allocate the `int values` inside the for-each loop into `byte[] sendingByte` array?

Comment: Java's `byte` is a signed 8-bit numeric type whose range is `-128` to `127` ([JLS 4.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1)). `233` is outside of this range and may cause communication problems on ModBus-RTU.

Comment: Probably this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte

Comment: edit was made to clarify the question