# Java not printing negative binaries right

Tags: java

So, i'm fairly new to java, and i'm a bit confused about the byte system. So I made this program that converts integers to their base two value.

```
class Bits
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte a;
        a = 5;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a)); /* prints 101 */
        a = -1;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a)); /* prints
        11111111111111111111111111111111*/
    }
}
```

It works as expected with positive numbers, but when I enter negative numbers, it gets weird. Now I know what two's compliment is, and it doesn't say that `-1` is `11111111111111111111111111111111`. It is supposed to be 11111111, right?  When I change `a` to an int `255`, which would be `-1` as a byte, I get the normal result, `11111111`, when I switch it to binary. Can someone explain to me why this is happening, or did I do something wrong.  (I am using java 8 and i'm on a mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.toBinaryString` accepts an `int` as an argument. So `a` is casted from `byte` to `int` before being passed to the method. And yes the two's complement of -1 of a 32 bits integer is `11111111111111111111111111111111`.

You should try with `Integer.toBinaryString(a & 0xFF)`. So that `a` is widened to `32` bits, but then `24` most relevant bits are discarded through masking. The bit sign is kept since you were starting from a `byte` so the result will be correct.

You can verify it by converting the truncating the int converted from `a` and the parse it as an `int` and converting it back to a `byte`:

```
int counter = 0;
for (byte a = -128; counter <= 256; ++a, ++counter)
{
   byte b = (byte)(Integer.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(a & 0xFF), 2) & 0xFF);
   System.out.println(a+" == "+b);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it.  But what does 0xFF mean?

Comment: Yes, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/how-does-java-convert-int-into-byte

Comment: What does the last part of the first answer mean?  Would it pretty much print a partly hidden integer?