# convert byte to integer in java using & and |

Tags: java, byte, data-conversion

I need to do a conversion from 1 byte to integer using `&` and `|`. The output after conversion must be an integer with these bytes:  (0xFF)(byte)(byte)(byte).

For example:

Input:

```
00000111
```

Output:

```
11111111000001110000011100000111
```

My code works if the byte is in range `[0, 127]`

```
int integer=7;
byte a=(byte)integer;
int b=(0xFF<<24)|(a<<16)|(a<<8)|(a);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
```

If the byte is in range `[-128, -1]`, it doesn't work

input:

```
10000000
```

Wrong output:

```
11111111111111111111111110000000
```

Expected output:

```
11111111100000001000000010000000
```

Comment: Try this: `int b = (0xFF<<24)|((a & 0xFF)<<16)^((a & 0xFF)<<8)^(a & 0xFF);`

Comment: replace `^` with `|`. I was trying XOR. try this `int b = (0xFF<<24)|((a & 0xFF)<<16)|((a & 0xFF)<<8)|(a & 0xFF);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because when you are shifting `a`, you are left with `1`s on the front.

For example:

`a<<16` gives you `11111111100000000000000000000000` but you want `100000000000000000000000`

`a<<8` gives you `11111111111111111000000000000000` but you want `1000000000000000`

So we need to mask those additional `1`s that are added on the front by doing `& 0xFF`

So replace this

`int b=(0xFF<<24)|(a<<16)|(a<<8)|(a);`

with this

`int b = (0xFF<<24)|((a & 0xFF)<<16)|((a & 0xFF)<<8)|(a & 0xFF);`

To know why we see `1`s on the front, here is a great explanation: [Odd behavior when Java converts int to byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842817/odd-behavior-when-java-converts-int-to-byte)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why the top bit is extended.

Comment: i work with images in processing and want to avoid using function [color()](https://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html) because is too slow for my program. Every pixel from the image is an integer and in this integer is stored the `ARGB` information like this  `AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBB`  ,and in my program i need `R=G=B , A=255`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  it is basically as left shift, and, and or operation.

```
byte a = (byte)240;
byte b = (byte)128;
byte c = 15;
int v = IntStream.of(0xFF, b, c, d).map(by-> by & 0xFF).reduce(0,
            (r, s) -> (r << 8) | s);

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(v));
```